# how to remove www part when url redirects to another folder?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I couldn't found this answer in Stackoverflow, but I have two domains and two websites. The main website is lying in the root folder (@/var/www) and my other website lies in (@/var/www/portfolio). The problem is that when I type www.me.com I want to url to change to me.com. How can I accomplish that.

My current .htaccess file looks like below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?me\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ portfolio/me/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` should look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.me.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://me.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?me\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ portfolio/me/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @Woho87 this has nothing to do with directories, it just redirects www.me.com to me.com

Comment: OK I added. I didn't the commented section of your answer. I also removed the flag `[L]` from my first RewriteRule. Though a small problem I don't want it to display the path `portfolio/me`?